# why i can't build iOS on android studio KMM kotlin

Tags: android, ios, xcode, build, kotlin-multiplatform

i update kotlin and kmm addon to last verion and create a new prjct no change any code
build andiod ok and work
but can't bild it on iOS
Xcode alon ok but project not mmk
i got this error
are i need other verion on xcode or what or kmm still beta for test?
are any one work with kmm? i just went to start iOS programming?
how i can start work on kmm its there can't build 1st applectin

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:compileKotlinIosX64'.
> Compilation finished with errors

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'iosApp' from project 'iosApp')
    cd /Users/bahaa/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/iosApp
    export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    export SDKROOT\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ContentView\~partial.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/bahaa/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/build/ios/iosApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/bahaa/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/iosApp/iosApp/iOSApp.swift
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/bahaa/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/iosApp/iosApp/ContentView.swift
    CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(4 failures)
```

kotlin kmm ios

update andiod studio and kmm kotlin